# Generating an n-dimensional array by applying function to all pairs

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Let `F` be a function that takes two arguments and returns a numeric *k*-vector (i.e. a numeric vector of length *k*) for some integer *k* > 1, and let `X` and `Y` be vectors of values suitable as first and second arguments (respectively) of `F`.

Is there a "functional" (i.e. loop-free), and convenient, way to generate the 3-dimensional array `A` such that, for all suitable `i` and `j`, the following expression is `TRUE`?

```
all.equal(A[i, j, ], F(X[[i]], Y[[j]]))
```

More generally, let `F` be a function that takes two arguments and returns a numeric *n*-dimensional array (where, `dim(F(x, y)) = D` is a constant *n*-vector, for all valid arguments `x` and `y`), and, as before, let `X` and `Y` be vectors of values suitable as first and second arguments (respectively) of `F`.

Is there a "functional" (i.e. loop-free), and convenient, way to generate the (*n* + 2)-dimensional array `A` (with `dim(A)` equal to `c(length(X), length(Y), D)`) such that, for all suitable `i` and `j`, the following expression is `TRUE`?

```
all.equal(A[i, j, , ... , ], F(X[[i]], Y[[j]]))
```

---

AFAICT, `outer` won't work for this.  For example, suppose that `F` is defined like this:

```
F <- function (m, n) {
    set.seed(m - n);
    array(runif(6), dim = c(3, 2))
}
```

This `F` takes two integers as arguments, and returns a 3 × 2 array of floating-point numbers.  E.g.:

```
F(3, 8)
```

> ```
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.7345948 0.6368477
> [2,] 0.3396928 0.9620946
> [3,] 0.1910453 0.3756567
> ```

But

```
outer(1:3, 1:3, Vectorize(F))
```

> ```
> Error in outer(1:3, 1:3, Vectorize(F)) : 
>   dims [product 9] do not match the length of object [54]
> ```

I figure the reason `outer` does not work here is because (emphasis added)

> outer(X, Y, FUN = "*", ...)
>
> ...
>
> ‘FUN’ is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus
>   any arguments in ‘...’).  It must be a vectorized function (or the
>   name of one) expecting at least two arguments and *returning a
>   value with the same length as the first (and the second)*.

---

**Update for Vlo:**

```
## the line below is cut-and-paste'd directly from comment
F<-function(m,n){set.seed(m - n);list(array(runif(6), dim = c(3, 2)))}; x = outer(1:3, 1:5, Vectorize(F, "m", "n"))
```

If I now inspect `x`, I get:
    x

> ```
>      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
> [1,] Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6
> [2,] Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6
> [3,] Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6 Numeric,6
> ```

This is not what I'm looking for.  For one thing, `dim(x)` here equals the vector `c(3, 5)`, whereas for the desired `x` it should be that

```
dim(x)
```

> ```
> [1] 3 5 3 2
> ```

and

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:5) {
        cat('\n', paste(c(i, j, '', ''), collapse = ', '), '\n')
        print(x[i, j, ,])
    }
}
```

> ```
>  1, 1, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
>  1, 2, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.4866672 0.1467027
> [2,] 0.1913653 0.2415895
> [3,] 0.9932719 0.5371012
>
>  1, 3, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8141134 0.2416691
> [2,] 0.5890751 0.9928682
> [3,] 0.1339374 0.9844079
>
>  1, 4, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.7705233 0.3878055
> [2,] 0.7820377 0.1221871
> [3,] 0.3802074 0.3378332
>
>  1, 5, ,  
>            [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.38668404 0.7800617
> [2,] 0.09064471 0.4887107
> [3,] 0.65027437 0.9742584
>
>  2, 1, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
> [3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897
>
>  2, 2, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
>  2, 3, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.4866672 0.1467027
> [2,] 0.1913653 0.2415895
> [3,] 0.9932719 0.5371012
>
>  2, 4, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8141134 0.2416691
> [2,] 0.5890751 0.9928682
> [3,] 0.1339374 0.9844079
>
>  2, 5, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.7705233 0.3878055
> [2,] 0.7820377 0.1221871
> [3,] 0.3802074 0.3378332
>
>  3, 1, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.1848823 0.1680519
> [2,] 0.7023740 0.9438393
> [3,] 0.5733263 0.9434750
>
>  3, 2, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
> [3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897
>
>  3, 3, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
>  3, 4, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.4866672 0.1467027
> [2,] 0.1913653 0.2415895
> [3,] 0.9932719 0.5371012
>
>  3, 5, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8141134 0.2416691
> [2,] 0.5890751 0.9928682
> [3,] 0.1339374 0.9844079
> ```

Comment: It really depends on the details and on what you mean by "loop-free". What happens if you pass a vector (rather than a single value) to either of the arguments of `F`? Can you tweak `F` in such a way it can handle vectorization? Ultimately, what `F` does? In any case, you can achieve what you want with a mix of `expand.grid` and `mapply`, but hardly it can be defined as `loop-free`.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're after, but it *sounds* like a job for `mapply`. At least the first part does.

Comment: `F<-function(m,n){set.seed(m - n);list(array(runif(6), dim = c(3, 2)))}; x = outer(1:3, 1:5, Vectorize(F, "m", "n"))` works. `Vectorize` is just a big old loop though.

Comment: @Frank: sorry about that (post fixed).

Comment: @Vlo: the snippet you posted does not produce the correct results.  (In my answer to my question I give an example of the desired output.)

Comment: `array(do.call(Vectorize(F), unname(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3))), dim=c(3, 3, 3, 2))` may work.

Comment: @kjo `array(outer(1:3, 1:5, Vectorize(F)))` Be sure to use the modified F() from above.

Comment: @Vlo: I've added an update to my post to answer your comment (I can't fit an answer in the space of a comment).

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's one clumsy solution.  **I post it in the hopes that it will elicit a better one** from someone with a better grasp of R than I have.

```
outer_nd <- function(x, y, f) {
    pairs <- unname(as.matrix(expand.grid(x, y)))
    n <- nrow(pairs)
    rows <- split(pairs, seq(n))
    values <- sapply(rows, function (p) do.call(f, as.list(p)))
    array(t(values), dim = c(length(x), length(y), dim(F(x[[1]], y[[1]]))))
}
```

This solution at least shows explicitly what I'm after.

For example, if `F` is defined like this

```
F <- function (m, n) {
    set.seed(m - n);
    array(runif(6), dim = c(3, 2))
}
```

...then

```
z <- outer_nd(1:2, 1:2, F)
dim(z)
```

> ```
>  [1] 2 2 3 2
> ```

and

```
for (i in 1:2) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
        cat('\n', paste(c(i, j, '', ''), collapse = ', '), '\n')
        print(z[i, j, ,])

        cat('\nF(', paste(c(i, j), collapse = ', '), ') =\n')
        print(F(i, j))
        cat('\n')
    }
}
```

> ```
>  1, 1, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
> F( 1, 1 ) =
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
>
>  1, 2, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.4866672 0.1467027
> [2,] 0.1913653 0.2415895
> [3,] 0.9932719 0.5371012
>
> F( 1, 2 ) =
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.4866672 0.1467027
> [2,] 0.1913653 0.2415895
> [3,] 0.9932719 0.5371012
>
>
>  2, 1, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
> [3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897
>
> F( 2, 1 ) =
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
> [3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897
>
>
>  2, 2, ,  
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
>
> F( 2, 2 ) =
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.8966972 0.5728534
> [2,] 0.2655087 0.9082078
> [3,] 0.3721239 0.2016819
> ```